# replace a SharePoint relative URL using powershell

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server, powershell, pnp-powershell, string

I want to replace `/sites/contoso` RelativeURL with `/teams/Int_Contoso` using PowerShell. Is there any regular expression to achieve this as we have changed the destination URLs during migration and now we want to compare source and destination list item counts for which we have to compare their server relative URLs.

Comment: Can you provide more details on what exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Are you looking for something like this?...https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/projectserver/Update-specified-59552f37

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple **-replace** function of Powershell to achieve this. If there are more than one item you can use this replace in a loop

An illustration of replace function

```
$originalText = "/sites/contoso"
$newText = $originalText -replace 'sites','teams'
```

> Value of $newText will be ***/teams/contoso***